# Submit to one Sharepoint Column from multiple Infopath fields?

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer, infopath

Is it possible to have multiple fields in one form, but have them submit to the same column in a sharepoint library?

If so can I have a detailed explanation as to how it would be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you can create a rule or action to concatenate values and store them in a hidden field, then promote that hidden field to the SharePoint list.  InfoPath pros feel free to correct me.

Comment: +1 nothing wrong with your idea

Comment: If it's a Library there is some more options when you submit, since you use the SharePoint Form Library template. You can specify the fields that will be published as columns in the Library. But the concatenate is the way to go imho :)

Comment: great idea, is there any way that I can have a default value, but not have it send?

Comment: Well that would be difficult if you are concatenating other field values.  The field could have a default value if it's not a browser based InfoPath form.  If you don't want to send it, just don't promote the column.  If you wanted to, could have a second hidden field on the form that if certain conditions were met, the values would be concatenated and then promoted.